# Call an array from within an array of structs in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I need some help, I need to pass an array to a function, but the array is declared in a struct.

```
struct person
{
   char m_dna[128];
};


int main ()
{
  person zombies[5000];   
  sequence (zombies.m_dna[])
}
```

I know thats wrong, and I cannont figure out how to call the array from within the struct.

Edit 1. I am trying to call the dna array, not a specific cell in the array, so I can assign the dna array characters defining a persons DNA.

Comment: zombies is an array, so specify element. Same for m_dna. So sequence (&zombies[0].m_dna[0]) if the function "sequence" takes a parameter which is a char*

Comment: are you trying to pass an array of 5000 persons into the function, or the m_dna of a specific person?

Comment: The m_dna of a specific person

Answer (score 0):

assuming `void foo(const char*)`

call

```
foo(zombies[42].m_dna);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
struct person
{
    char m_dna[128];
};

int sequence( char *p1 )
{
    p1[ 0 ] = 0x21;
    return( 0 );
}

int main ()
{
    person zombies[5000];   
    sequence( zombies[1].m_dna )
}
```

Comment: I just need the m_dna[].